# SignalR 64 bit Issue

Tags: c#, signalr

I wrote a SignalR application that works perfectly  when built using Any CPU configuration.  When I built it using 64 bit configuration,  it just fails with the message:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
SignalR.MBNDealerPosition.js:175 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

essentially the hub is not being created.  I have exhausted all resources and hence seek help at stackoverflow.  Please advice. I am using Visual Studio 2013.  I need to build the application using 64 bit configuration because I have to now include a dll that is available only as a 64 bit dll.

Comment: Can you post your 'client' code?

Comment: The only difference I see in the debug console when the run in the visual studio environment is that when running the 64 bit dll there is a message:'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'

Comment: Please note that the ONLY difference is that I change the config to 64 bit from Any CPU.

Comment: If you check out the [WPF/WinForms sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b) you will easily see there is no bitness issue at all. About the specific you hit, it must be caused by something else. Try to remove unnecessary things from your project to see who causes the error.

Comment: I solved the problem unexpectedly.  I just created a separate path for the x64 exe and the problem magically went away!  I have no clue why the problem occurs when Any CPU and x64 exes are built to the same path.  Any suggestions appreciated,

Comment: Bad news.  the problem reappears when I try to link to 64 bit dll. I cannot even get the SignalR Ticker Sample to work as an x64 dll.

Comment: This is still unresolved. Lex Li, I will try building your WPF sample using x^4 config and see if that works.